# phpstorm не видит /var/www/

Tags: phpstorm

права *drwxrwxrwx  4 root root   4096 ноя 19 11:20 www*
[image: скриншот]

Comment: судя по скриншоту папка www может быть просто ниже, пролистайте вниз стрелками на клавиатуре

Comment: Ползунок до упора)

Answer (score 0):

Удали PhpStorm и установи его с помощью JetBrains Toolbox

Тут можно скачать: https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/toolbox-app/

Тут инструкция по установке: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/installation-guide.html

Лично мне помогло

Comment: проверю позже. спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

root root это не те права, что должны быть на папке, т.к. шторм открывается от прав пользователя, а не от root'a. Установи пользователя, обычно это так:

```
chown -R username:www-data /path/to/var/www
```

www-data обычно под этим пользователем работают другие по, например апач. Как правило его ставят в виде доступа для группы

username - своего пользователя